# make element in front of others ... z-index?

Tags: jquery, html, css, z-index

i have just added a floating navigation menu to my website.

The problem is that some images of the page are still coming over it

I tried

```
z-index: 99999;
```

but it didn't change anything.

Check out the test page to see the problem live (scroll down the page and you will see)
https://www.ni-dieu-ni-maitre.com/index2.php

Comment: can you be more specific which element ?

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use 'position' in your css in case that you want use z-index. Use one of this:

```
position: relative;
position: absolute;
position: fixed;
```

Answer (score 0):

Mobile WebKit and Chrome 22+, a new stacking context is created by `position: fixed`, even when `z-index` is `auto`.

So the stacking context hierarchy looks like this:

- document root (z-index `0`)

  - `#element` (z-index `9998`)
  - `#element2` (z-index `0`)

    - `.aboveElement` (z-index `9999`)
    - `.belowElement` (z-index `9997`)

You cannot compare `9998` with `9999` or `9997` to determine stacking order.  Instead, `9999` is compared with `9997` to determine which of `.aboveElement` and `.belowElement` is further in front, and then once everything inside `#element2` is stacked in that context, it's treated as a single layer at z-index `0` which gets stacked behind `#element` at z-index `9998`.

Read [the stacking context in mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context.)

Read [the stacking change for `fixed` elements in Chrome](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/09/Stacking-Changes-Coming-to-position-fixed-elements).